# Preserve PhpStorm embedded terminal history

Tags: macos, terminal, phpstorm

Whenever I start a new session in PhpStorm embedded terminal it doesn't have any history of previously entered commands and by pressing `Up` key it usually shows some command I executed ages ago via macOS terminal.

Is it possible to make the embedded terminal preserve history of commands, that were entered in another embedded terminal before.

Comment: Works fine with [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible currently, please follow [IDEA-155571](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155571) and linked tickets for updates